# SQL Server Temp Database Monitor Tools

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Please suggest best tool to monitor temp db activity to find the objects which have excessive temp db usage.

Comment: Did you searched a bit. You could have found out following documents https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and reference for tempdb.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966545.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Before we get into identifying queries that use tempdb, it is very important to understand what all activities in SQL Server (both internal & user activities), which use the tempdb database. Broadly you can classify these into 3 categories:- Kindly read on them.

1.Internal Objects
2.Version Stores
3.User Objects

I believe you do not require any tools as such. You need to have few queries handy with you:

---------Below query helps you identify  which type of tempdb objects are consuming  space

```
SELECT
SUM (user_object_reserved_page_count)*8 as user_obj_kb,
SUM (internal_object_reserved_page_count)*8 as internal_obj_kb,
SUM (version_store_reserved_page_count)*8  as version_store_kb,
SUM (unallocated_extent_page_count)*8 as freespace_kb,
SUM (mixed_extent_page_count)*8 as mixedextent_kb
FROM sys.dm_db_file_space_usage
```

If user_obj_kb is the highest consumer, then you that objects are being created by user queries like local or global temp tables or table variables. Also don’t forget to check if there are any permanent tables created in TempDB. Very rare, but I’ve seen this happening.

If version_store_kb is the highest consumer, then it means that the version store is growing faster than the clean up. Most likely there are long running transactions or open transaction (Sleeping state), 
which are preventing the cleanup and hence not release tempdb space back.

---------Query that identifies the currently active T-SQL query, it’s text and the Application that is consuming a lot of tempdb space

```
  SELECT es.host_name , es.login_name , es.program_name,
  st.dbid as QueryExecContextDBID, DB_NAME(st.dbid) as QueryExecContextDBNAME,    st.objectid as ModuleObjectId,
  SUBSTRING(st.text, er.statement_start_offset/2 + 1,(CASE WHEN   er.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),st.text)) * 2 ELSE er.statement_end_offset 
    END - er.statement_start_offset)/2) as Query_Text,
tsu.session_id ,tsu.request_id, tsu.exec_context_id, 
   (tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count - tsu.user_objects_dealloc_page_count) as   OutStanding_user_objects_page_counts,
  (tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count - tsu.internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) as       OutStanding_internal_objects_page_counts,
   er.start_time, er.command, er.open_transaction_count, er.percent_complete,            er.estimated_completion_time, er.cpu_time, er.total_elapsed_time, er.reads,er.writes, 
   er.logical_reads, er.granted_query_memory
    FROM sys.dm_db_task_space_usage tsu inner join sys.dm_exec_requests er 
   ON ( tsu.session_id = er.session_id and tsu.request_id = er.request_id) 
   inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions es ON ( tsu.session_id = es.session_id ) 
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st
  WHERE (tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count+tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count) > 0
  ORDER BY (tsu.user_objects_alloc_page_count - tsu.user_objects_dealloc_page_count)+  (tsu.internal_objects_alloc_page_count - tsu.internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) 
    DESC
```

-------- TRACE FLAG 1118

This trace flag is available starting with SQL 2000 SP3 to reduce tempdb contention by forcing uniform extent allocations as opposed to mixed extent allocations. This trace flag is only to be used if you seeing contention (wait_Stats) on the PFS/GAM pages like 2:1:1 etc.. More internal details on this trace flag is available in Paul Randal’s blog post http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-tf-1118/

Most importantly kindly go through this complete article from msdn which would really help you understand the usage of tempdb and how to monitor issues related on same!

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966545.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the details, Kapil. Please let me know how to get the execution count of an sp/any database object against tempdb per second/minute?

Comment: @TonyDevraj: You can post that as a separate question on the forum and would be answered.If above answer works for u, you can mark that as answer to you're question thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 then SQL Server 2012 Best Practices Analyzer (BPA) is a one free diagnostic Analyzer tool. Prior to starting the first BPA scan, ensure that the account you are using has a SQL Server login with sysadmin role membership. Otherwise you will encounter the error "Login does not exist or is not a member of the Systems Administrator role".